# SwiftUI Horizontal Split View with Draggable Splitter Freezing During Drag

Tags: swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a horizontal split view in SwiftUI with a draggable splitter that allows me to resize the two rectangles on each side of the splitter. I want the layout to be horizontally divided, similar to a classic split view.

I have attempted to achieve this by using a GeometryReader, DragGesture, and two rectangles in a VStack. The rectangles represent the two areas, and the Divider acts as the draggable splitter. Here's the code I'm using:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var rectangle1Height: CGFloat = 200
    @State private var rectangle2Height: CGFloat = 200
    @State private var dragOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var isDragging = false

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: rectangle1Height)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                self.isDragging = true
                                self.dragOffset = value.location.y
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                self.isDragging = false
                            }
                    )
                    .offset(y: self.isDragging ? self.dragOffset - rectangle1Height/2 : 0)

                Divider() // The splitter

                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: rectangle2Height)
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                self.isDragging = true
                                self.dragOffset = value.location.y - (geometry.size.height - rectangle2Height)
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                self.isDragging = false
                            }
                    )
                    .offset(y: self.isDragging ? self.dragOffset + rectangle2Height/2 : 0)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

While this code somewhat works for resizing the rectangles using the draggable splitter, I'm encountering a freezing issue during dragging. The app becomes unresponsive and freezes until I release the drag gesture.

I suspect that the continuous updates to the view while dragging might be causing the freezing. I tried using the onEnded modifier to update the view only after the drag ends, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Is there a way to create a horizontally resizable split view with a draggable splitter in SwiftUI without encountering this freezing problem?